# Loading subcategories in TreeView on click Dotvvm

Tags: dotvvm

I use business pack treeview component for menu. My goal is to retrieve only top level menu without subcategories. Subcategories will show only on user icon click (+ / - icons) or on menu item click.

So basically when I click on "a" or icon binded to this menu object, I want to send request to my server to get his subcategories and so on. I dont want to get everything in one request.

[image]

As I noticed there are two click handlers in view.

1) Use `Changed`property - when I use this property to handle click events, I successfully get correct object into my `CategorySelectedList`, but it only register clicks directly on text label. For icon it doesnt work anymore and also category menu will not expand.

2) Use `Events.Click`property - when I use this property to handle click events. I dont even get correct object into my `CategorySelectedList` property, but category menu will expand in this case.

I cant send object Id from my view into `SetActiveMenuNode` method so I have to take it directly from my `CategorySelectedList` but each aproach has his own problems.

Is there any solution for this?

ModelView

```
public List<CategoryListDTO> AdminMenuList { get; set; } = new List<CategoryListDTO>();
public List<CategoryListDTO> AdminMenuSelectedList { get; set; } = new List<CategoryListDTO>();
public void SetActiveMenuNode()
{
    var selected = AdminMenuSelectedList.FirstOrDefault();
}

//načítání podkategorií 
public StaticCommandBindingExpression LoadChildren { get; set; } = new StaticCommandBindingExpression(new CompiledBindingExpression( //something here));
```

My view

```
<dot:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<section class="content">
    <bp:TreeView DataSource="{value: AdminMenuList}"
                 SelectedValues="{value: AdminMenuSelectedList}"
                 ItemKeyBinding="{value: Id}"
                 ItemHasChildrenBinding="{value: HasCategories}"
                 ItemChildrenBinding="{value: AssignedToCategory}"
                 LoadChildren="{staticCommand: _parent.MyMethod()}"
                 Changed="{command: SetActiveMenuNode()}"          
                 >
        <p>{{value: Name}}</p>
    </bp:TreeView>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Unfortunately there is no solution right now. We have this feature in our backlog and will implement it when possible.</strike>

We have implemented this feature in version 1.1.5-rc1. The `TreeView` control has a new property `LoadChildren` of type `StaticCommandBindingExpression`. Here is an example on how to use it.

**ViewModel.cs**

```cs
[AllowStaticCommand]
public static IEnumerable<Item> LoadChildren(Item parent)
{
    return LoadYourChildrenFromSomewhere(parent.Id);
}
```

**View.dothtml**

```html
<bp:TreeView LoadChildren="{staticCommand: ViewModel.LoadChildren(_this)}" />
```

Please note that DI is not yet supported for static commands (it's [coming](https://github.com/riganti/dotvvm/pull/416)). You need to create the required services yourself or resolve them from global service provider.

Comment: I have a good news for you. This feature will be available in next beta version.

Comment: Thanks for information. When the next beta version should be released?

Comment: We have released version 1.1.5-rc1 where this feature is included.

Comment: Thanks for info, gonna try as soon as possible. Upvoting and accepting answer

Comment: Take a look at `LoadChildren` command. It accepts the expanded item as argument and should return it's children / descendants.

Comment: Is it possible to get this version via NuGet? I dont see any this version in version list. I also check your dotvvm feed and no success also.

Comment: So after visual studio restart it finally showed up in NuGet.

Comment: Updated my question. Working on it right now, if I get it right, i have to create and initialize property with type `StaticCommandBindingExpression ` and after that I have to pass that expanded item ( in my case it is my `SelectedValue` so `AdminMenuSelectedList` I guess ) but how can I pass it?  Is it possible to create some sample?

Comment: I found how i can register service in `dotvvm startup`. What I cant figure out, how I can create that service for `staticCommand`. Do you have some documentation for this or if you could provide some sample I would be so grateful.

Comment: It depends on your IoC container and your app configuration. If you are using ASP.NET Core, you may find this [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/issues/294) useful. But I can't help you with that.